# I want to convert 20080910173240 to 2008-09-10T17:32:40.000+0000 in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have tried below command but getting some error :

```
SELECT convert(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(10),20080910173240,127))
```

> Error : Msg 8115, Level 16, State 5, Line 7 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting numeric to data type varchar.

Comment: you want to convert to datetime, datetime2, datetimeoffset or just varchar?

Comment: I want to output from 20080910173240 to 2008-09-10T17:32:40.000+0000.

Comment: As a start increase the VARCHAR length to a high enough number (not 10). You can try using DATETIMEFROMPARTS and spliting your big number properly.

Comment: done : select convert(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(250),20080910173240,127))

Comment: You have a 14 digit number and the first step of your attempt is to try to convert it to `varchar(10)`? What are you expecting the result of that conversion to *be*?

Comment: i am getting Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the question still has a right to be answered... Quite often DWH systems store date as numeric value. `FORMAT` can be used to apply mask on top of numbers to get it back to a datetime that SQL Server understands

```
-- 2008-09-10 17:32:40.000
SELECT CAST(FORMAT(20080910173240, '####-##-## ##:##:##') AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` without using string functions:

```
DECLARE @MyAwkwardDateTime BIGINT = 20080910173240

SELECT
    GeneratedDateTime = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        T.Year,
        T.Month,
        T.Day,
        T.Hour,
        T.Minute,
        T.Second,
        0)
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Year = CONVERT(INT, @MyAwkwardDateTime / 10000000000),
        Month = @MyAwkwardDateTime / 100000000 % 100,
        Day = @MyAwkwardDateTime / 1000000 % 100,
        Hour = @MyAwkwardDateTime / 10000 % 100,
        Minute = @MyAwkwardDateTime / 100 % 100,
        Second = @MyAwkwardDateTime % 100
    ) AS T
```

Result:

```
GeneratedDateTime
2008-09-10 17:32:40.000
```

No need for subquery, I just used it so it's easier to see each time portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will just the format your number as needed.

```
SELECT FORMAT(20080910173240, '####-##-## ##:##:##')
```

This will convert into date format as well.

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, FORMAT(20080910173240, '####-##-## ##:##:##'), 101);
```

***The output would be 2008-09-10 17:32:40.000***